# What event is generate when ContentControl.Content is set?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, contentcontrol

I need to subscribe to an event for a control when `ContentControl.Content` is set.

Please, what event can I put in my code to set it?

I tried to use `SourceUpdated` and `DataContextChanged`, but it is not working.

Comment: Sorry, where is this event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this webpage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc794276.aspx):

The strange approach to receiving notifications of changes in dependency properties involves dynamically creating both a dependency property and data binding. If you're writing a class that descends from DependencyObject, have access to an object that contains dependency properties, and need to be notified when one of those dependency properties changes, you can create a dependency property and a binding on the fly to give you the information you need.

`ContentControl.Content` is a dependency property.

Comment: Thank you! I don't know what can I do yet, but I know a direction now

Comment: @Lai32290 I use a stand-alone DependencyObject whose sole purpose is to bind to and raise a ValueChanged event for a particular property. The technique is described [here](http://agsmith.wordpress.com/2008/04/07/propertydescriptor-addvaluechanged-alternative/).

Comment: Thank you very much! I solved my problem with DependencyPropertyDescriptor, it is very useful!

Comment: @Lai32290 Unless you can guarantee that `DependencyPropertyDescriptor.RemoveValueChanged` will be called for each control, it will always keep the controls alive (memory leak). Although if you're only listening to one control (e.g. your main window), it's not a problem.